# copying a std::vector to a qvector

Tags: c++, qt

I tried copy content of one vector to a `QVector` using the following

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin());
```

However the destination `QVector` still is empty.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use [`QVector::fromStdVector`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#fromStdVector)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at:

```
std::vector<T> QVector::toStdVector () const

QVector<T> QVector::fromStdVector ( const std::vector<T> & vector ) [static]
```

[From docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#fromStdVector)

Comment: tried that. as `MyQvector.fromStdVector(MyStedVector);` still the qvector is empty

Comment: @Rajeshwar: because it static method, try: MyQvector = QVector::fromStdVector( MyStedVector );

Answer (score 10):

'fromStdVector' has been explicitly marked deprecated recently.
Use following code:

```
std::vector<...> stdVec;

// ...       

QVector<...> qVec = QVector<...>(stdVec.begin(), stdVec.end());
```

Comment: I really don't see why QT team has deprecated this function. it seems quite useful and more easy to write in my mind ...

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating a new `QVector` with the contents of a `std::vector` you can use the following code as an example:

```
   std::vector<T> stdVec;
   QVector<T> qVec = QVector<T>::fromStdVector(stdVec);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers mentioned, you should use the following method to convert a `QVector` to a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<T> QVector::toStdVector() const
```

And the following static method to convert a `std::vector` to a `QVector`:

```
QVector<T> QVector::fromStdVector(const std::vector<T> & vector)
```

Here is an example of how to use `QVector::fromStdVector` (taken from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#fromStdVector)):

```
std::vector<double> stdvector;
stdvector.push_back(1.2);
stdvector.push_back(0.5);
stdvector.push_back(3.14);

QVector<double> vector = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(stdvector);
```

Don't forget to specify the type after the second `QVector` (it should be `QVector<double>::fromStdVector(stdvector)`, not `QVector::fromStdVector(stdvector)`). Not doing so will give you an annoying compiler error.