# Declaration of Qvector from std vector

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qvector

I'm trying to create a Qvector from and std::Vector.

I can of course copy it element by element using a for loop, but I'm looking for a better way to do it.

So I tried:

```
QVector<double> qv  = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(values) ;
```

This works fine but I get a warning that it's deprecated.

I followed Hadi Navapour's suggestion from [copying a std::vector to a qvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129656/copying-a-stdvector-to-a-qvector/18129776)

and tried the following:

```
    QVector<double> qv  = QVector<double>(values.begin(), values.end());
```

but this code with begin() and end() does not compile, I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to
> ‘QVector::QVector(std::vector::iterator,
> std::vector::iterator)’
> QVector qv  = QVector(values.begin(), values.end());

I believe this is supposed to use the following constructor `QVector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`

I can't get it to work.

Could someone please explain the right non-deprecated way to copy an std::vector to a Qvector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `QVector` constructor taking a pair of iterators was introduced in Qt 5.14. You are probably using an earlier version.

Comment: good point, I will check my qt version once I'm on my pc that has QT again and get back to you! but assuming I'm using a version earlier than 5.14, and don't want to use the deprecated fromStdVector, what should I do?

Comment: Well, `fromStdVector` is deprecated as of Qt 5.14, precisely because a replacement is made available. If you can't use either, then you are left with pushing elements one by one in a loop; you could write a helper function for that, similar to `fromStdVector`

Comment: `Qvector`, `qvector`, `std::Vector` -- who cares, as long as it compiles? Oh, wait...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, just checked my qt creator help > about,  "Based on Qt 5.15.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)" my qt 5.15 should be able to support the iterators constructor...
I can do a manual copy or just use the deprecated function, I'm just curious to know why I'm getting this weird behavior...

Comment: Iterator constructor works for me here, building with 5.15.1. You must be including wrong headers from older version somehow. Double-check your build configuration.

Comment: Can you try a newer GCC Version? Despite not explicitly stating it, GCC 5 is just C++11, while if I recall correctly, Qt may need C++14 for such range constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#fromStdVector enforces to use range constructors from version 5.14.

so may be you can use version flags for your implementation.

try as said below, if you are interested.

```
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,14,0)
    QVector<double> qv  = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(values) ;
#else
    QVector<double> qv  = QVector<double>(values.begin(), values.end());
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as I just mentioned in my comment on the original post my qt version is 5.15, it should be able to support the iterators constructor...
I can do a manual copy or just use the deprecated function, I'm just curious to know why I'm getting this weird behavior...